# Is it safe to have pointers to elements in Data Structures? (c++ with QT)

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, memory

I have the following structure on the software I am developing:

```
ClassA:
QHash<int, ClassB>

ClassB:
QHash<int, ClassC>

ClassC:
QMap<ID, QSharedPointer<ClassD> > (this is because I need to have the items ordered)
QHash<int, QSharedPointer<ClassD> > (this exists so I can access an item via id)
```

My question is if it is safe to have a pointer, that will be edited, to an element inside a data structure. I have been getting errors while trying to debug in which the debugger is unable to stop at a break point and I get a SIGTRAP error, but I am not sure if it is related to a memory issue on this.

To give a better example, related to the software I'm developing I have a `QHash<int, Take>` that represents a list of videos. The user will be editing only one video at a time, so I have a pointer to the current video, which is a Take inside the Hash. Each Take has a bunch of parameters that can be edited but the most common is a QMap of Notes. Is is safe to do something like this?

```
Take *currentTake = &takes[currentTakeId];

----//---

currentTake->addNote(new Note());
currentTake->changeSomeParameter();
etc
```

Comment: Maybe if you describe your task instead of current solution you develop than somebody will be able to find even better solution? I mean: can you add the actual task description to the question text?

Comment: Maintain a pointer does not make much difference in a data structure than anywhere else. You must be sure no one deletes your pointer during your procedure, or use a [QPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html#details) or [QSharedPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#details) and test it. Your problem is probably more about design : get a clear overview of object lifetimes, avoid global variables, use references when it makes sense (when you are sure the object will remain alive as least as long as the reference variable).

Comment: @AlexanderVX I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean exactly. I can add a more thorough description but I wanted to keep things as simple as possible and make the question more broad. Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough but I guess my question was: "Is it safe to have a pointer (which will be edited, as in, values inside of the class it points to will be changed) that is inside a QT container (in this case I use QHash and QMap, mainly, although QList is also going to be used). I make sure the pointer is never deleted when it's still in use.

Comment: @ymoreau Yes, I am never deleting the object when the reference is still being used. I guess my question is if it is absolutely safe to have a pointer to an element inside a QMap, QHash, whatever data structure, when that element will be edited. E.g. Is it safe to have ClassB *element and do element->add(ClassC) (or any other changes to that pointer)? I will change the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether (or how long) it is safe to keep a pointer/reference to an element of a collection is up to that collection. For example, a `std::vector` invalidates all pointers into it on reallocation, and removal/insertion without reallocation invalidates (well, changes what they point to) all pointers beyond the insertion/removal point. A `std::list` on the other hand is stable; pointers only get invalidated if the specific element they point to is removed.

A collection should generally document its invalidation behavior. Unfortunately, the Qt collections don't. Reading their documentation tells us that `QMap` is a red-black balanced binary tree, and `QHash` is a separate chaining hash table, so they should both have the `std::list` behavior for invalidation, but there's no *guarantee* of that. (For example, `QHash` could store the head entry directly in the bucket list, which would mean that rehashing would invalidate most pointers, and removing an element could invalidate pointers to elements in the same bucket.)

Comment: Would this be something that can easily be tested? That is, either it is safe or it isn't and it will crash the app upon changing stuff in the pointer after inserting new data/removing? I did a quick test myself in which I added 3 takes, then selected take 2 as the current and deleted the first. Then continue editing the current (take 2) and everything seemed to work fine.

Comment: Qt is open-source, so it can be rather easily found out by code inspection. Looking at `QMap` and `QHash`, they're both safe (https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/tools/qhash.h#L70 shows that there is nothing special going on, just a plain single-linked list in every bucket). Of course, you'd have to re-check on every Qt upgrade to see if they changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Use references**, the data container of your example is storing values of object and returns reference to the object when you do `takes[currentTakeId]`. 
You can do this

```
Take &currentTake = takes.value(currentTakeId]); 
// same as 'takes[currentTakeId]'
// but avoid to create empty element if 'currentTakeId' has no element

----//---

currentTake.addNote(new Note());
currentTake.changeSomeParameter();

// do not change 'takes' as long as you use 'currentTake'
```

Your idea is fine (and more or less the same), you can retrieve the address and work on the pointer **as long as the container is not modified** when you are using this pointer. Because the data container might copy your element if resizing, or delete it, and then the pointer would be invalid.

If your objects Take are quite big you can lose performance because of the copy when the container is resized or passed by value (and copied). Then storing pointer can be a solution, or use the implicit sharing pattern of Qt on your data class.

Comment: But the function .value returns a const object. You can't make a reference to it. The reason I am using a pointer instead of a reference is because I can't store a reference as a class variable. The editing occurs in more than on function.